# Updating a JTable after using RowFilter

Tags: java, jtable, rowfilter, tablerowsorter

I was able to attach a filter to the GraphTable (which is extended from the JTable). I was trying out a sample filter which filters all the rows starting with the letter "A".

```
final GraphTable<Composite, ?> leftTable =
        (GraphTable<Composite, ?>) newMapPanel.getLeft();
final RowSorter<TableModel> sorter =
        new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(((JTable)leftTable).getModel());

RowFilter<Object, Object> startsWithAFilter = new RowFilter<Object,Object>() {
   public boolean include(Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry) {

      for (int i = entry.getValueCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if(entry.getValue(i) != null)
          {
              if (entry.getValue(i).toString().startsWith("A")) {
                // The value starts with "A", so do not include it, filter it.
                return false;
              }
          }
      }
      // None of the columns start with "a"; return true so that this
      // entry is shown
      return true;
   }
};

((DefaultRowSorter<TableModel, Integer>) sorter).setRowFilter(startsWithAFilter);
((JTable)leftTable).setRowSorter(sorter); 
((JTable)leftTable).updateUI();
```

The include method returns false for all the entries starting with "A" and returns true for others.

But this updation is not reflected in the Table. Neither `((JTable)leftTable).updateUI()` nor the `((JTable)leftTable).revalidate()` updated the Table. I believe this filter those
rows from the view. What should I do to make the changes get reflected in the view immediately.

Kindly give me any directions or suggestions ?

Comment: Dany, can be something wrong with your "GraphTable" implementation, as I have checked your code with a JTable and it works with "updateUI" and with "repaint()".

Comment: You should never use updateUI(). Read the API documentation. You are NOT changing the LAF. This is a hack people use because they aren't doing proper coding. You should also not need to invoke repaint() either. Without a proper SSCCE (http://sscce.org) there is not much we can do. You can always read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Table" for a working example of using a filter.

Comment: Hi All, I have got the answer for my question. The underlying model of my GraphTable is actually a jXTreeTable. We cannot use setRowsorter() in a JXTreetable, because setRowSorter is overridden to do nothing in JXTreeTable, the reason being JXtreeTable is not sortable.

Comment: Dany: are you able to post and accept your own answer?